# 1999 Jeep Grand Cherokee power loss (electric)

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting, jeep, power

I have 1999 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo with all-wheel drive 4.7 power locks and windows etc.

In the last few weeks I have a complete electrical power loss. Like the battery is taken out of the Jeep when I drive,  or in the morning to go to work,  its like no power no lights no nothing then after a 5- 15 minutes everything just comes back on.

I have:

- hooked up jumper cables to try to help, but nothing
- had advance auto check battery and they say it fine only 1 1/2 years old
- checked the cables and they good no corrosion and look in good shape

I have talked to a couple of shops around me and they said that they would need to recreate the problem in order to tell me but there is no pattern on when it will do it.

So if anyone has an ideas, please help. I love this Jeep.

Comment: I have the same symptoms, but my problem has proven to be the ignition. The accessory groupk e.g. wipers, radio, interior lights, etc. all go dead. Sometimes the power returns on its own. I can always get it back by switching the key off, then on.

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow the positive battery cable from the battery to the next connection. It may be the starter or a post mounted to a power distribution block in the engine bay. Check that connection for tightness and corrosion. It is possible (I had this happen in my truck) that the battery terminal to cable connection is bad. In my case it was the old molded lead style terminal. The connection would pass 12 volts but would not carry enough current to crank the starter. The other thing to check is the ground side of the circuit. Follow the ground cable to the end. It is typically attached to the block. Make sure it is tight on both ends. You may also have a ground strap or cable from the block to the body. They can be difficult to locate as they seem to put them where they can't be seen. The next time the problem occurs get out your jumper cables. Attach one clamp to the negative terminal of the battery.The color doesn't matter. Attach the corresponding clamp,(use the same color clamp) to something metal on the motor. Use an alternator bracket,a/c mount etc. then try to start the engine. If it starts you know the problem is in the ground side of the circuit, or the problem just went away as it has before.